# Import in Processing JS?

Tags: javascript, processing

I've looked all over the internet but I couldn't find anywhere to explain to me how `import` works in Processing JS.

How would I do something like this?

---

*block.pde*

```
void drawRect() {
    fill(255, 0, 0);
    rect(30, 30, width - 60, height - 60);
}
```

---

*core.pde*

```
import block;

void setup() {
    size(800, 500);
    background(240);
    frameRate(120);
}

void draw() {
    background(240);
    drawRect();
}
```

---

So how would you use `import`? Can you import files that you've made yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need to import anything.

This:

> Create a web page that includes Processing.js as well as a `<canvas>` with info about where to get your sketch file (you can specify multiple *.pde files, separating them with spaces): 
>   1 `<script src="processing-1.3.6.min.js"></script>`
>   2 `<canvas data-processing-sources="hello-web.pde"></canvas>`
>   Load your web page, and it will parse, translate, and run your sketch in the browser.

from [here](http://processingjs.org/articles/jsQuickStart.html#quickstart), suggests that you should be able to just do something like:

```
<canvas data-processing-sources="core.pde block.pde"></canvas>
```

And then you should be able to call drawRect() without any import statement just like in a standard sketch with multiple pdes.

Comment: Ah, cool. So just add multiple things in `processing-sources`. :) Thanks!